# Heat generated on thin disc plate in magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, magnetic-fields

There are the eddy currents in thin circular copper plate thickness h and radius a, in a harmonic magnetic field which is perpendicular to plate and the effect of auto-induction is negligible. Now we must get average heat generated on it.

As I said, I have final equation, but how do you get to this eqution. Does anyone know solution from first step to this?
$$
\overline P=\frac{1}{16}\pi\gamma ha^4B_0^2\omega
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111719/2451

Answer (score 0):

In macroscopic EM theory, we can calculate heat being evolved due to electric current in unit time in region $V$ by 
$$
\int_V \mathbf  j \cdot \mathbf E\,dV.
$$

If you express electric field in terms of $B_0$ and $\omega$ and assume Ohm's law $\mathbf j = \frac{1}{\gamma}\mathbf E$ where $\gamma$ is resistivity, you should be able to derive formula similar or same to the one you wrote above.